# How do I compare current diskspace with previous days diskspace in KQL

Tags: kql

I have a query that shows the server with the least diskspace free but I wanted to add a column that shows the space compared to a historic figure (to capture any sudden decrease)

And I seem to be able to only get it to work for a few occurrences

my code so far

```
let start = ago(24h); 
let End_date = ago(48h); 

let Curr =Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space" 
| where TimeGenerated >ago(1h)
|extend dim =strcat(Computer,InstanceName)
|summarize CurrentVal= max(CounterValue) by Computer,InstanceName;

let Prev = Perf 
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space" 
| where TimeGenerated >End_date 
|where TimeGenerated <start
|extend dim =strcat(Computer,InstanceName)
|summarize YesterdayVal=max(CounterValue) by Computer,InstanceName;

Curr 
|join kind = leftouter Prev on InstanceName and Computer
//|extend diff = CurrentVal - YesterdayVal
//|extend Diskspace =CurrentVal 
//|project Computer, InstanceName, Diskspace, diff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
let start = ago(24h); 
let End_date = ago(48h); 
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > End_date
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space"
| extend Current= TimeGenerated > start
| summarize
  Diskspace= maxif(CounterValue, Current),
  Diff= maxif(CounterValue, Current) - maxif(CounterValue, not(Current))
  by Computer, InstanceName
```